# Why does my Git submodule lose all execution permissions even if they are present in repo of submodule?

Tags: git

I have a Git repo with a submodule. In the repository for the submodule there are a number of files with the execution flag set, but when I update the submodule from the main repo all the execution permissions are gone. I fetch the submodule using:

```sh
git submodule update --init
```

In the repo of the submodule I can see that execution permissions are tracked by git, i.e.

```sh
git ls-files -s . | grep 100755
```

outputs a list, e.g.:

```sh
100755 ccc5c19ba7ae81e9bd990bde077640e3154b383f 0       some_file
100755 23c27559f40ede338a41b40c43b74180bdc494a4 0       some other_file
```

In the directory of the submodule, no execution permissions are set and the same command as above results in an empty list since all files seems to be stored as "100644" by Git. Both the main repository and the repository of the submodule have the `core.filemode` property set to `true`.

**How can I get the correct execution permissions in the submodule? I am out of ideas...**

I use Debian Linux (using WSL) and Git version 2.31.1.

Comment: "Using WSL" is likely the problem: Windows has no execute permissions. Make sure you use a Linux *file system* as well as the WSL facilities.

Comment: I am using the home directory of Debian. It uses ext4 according to `df -Th`. WSL should handle this. Also, I can set access permissions and they work. It just doesn't work with submodules. But, sure, I should test on a "proper" Linux.

Comment: Hm, OK, seems like it should "just work" then. The `core.filemode` setting of `true` seems to match the set-access-permissions-and-they-work part, too => "should just work". But... doesn't!